# How to enable ReCaptcha for all Laravel Jetstream auth pages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am using `Laravel` with `Jetstream`  as authentication system .

I am trying to add google ReCaptcha, but there is no specific place inside the project to add custom validation rules ( captcha verification rules ) and I don't want to modify the vendor folder . What is the proper way to enable captcha in all Jetstream auth pages ( login, register, reset password ... ) ?